# how to expend UIButton width from right to left only

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uianimation

i will like to know how to expend the width of an UIButton to the left only, pretty much like app store button that will expend towards the left. however i have multiple button to expend.

EDIT this is the working code:

```
//viewdidload
buttonCaption = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//default placement
buttonCaption.frame = CGRectMake(245, 385, 70, 30); //default width size
[self nextAnimation:buttonCaption.frame.size.width];
```

---

pass default value to animation

```
-(void)nextAnimation:(float)previousWidth {

//button setting
buttonCaption.titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin ;
//buttonCaption.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
[[buttonCaption layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[[buttonCaption layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[buttonCaption layer] setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.7] CGColor]];   
[buttonCaption.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 25, 25)];   
CGSize stringsize = [tempCaption sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];  
CGFloat diff = stringsize.width - previousWidth;
NSLog(@"diff %f",diff);



 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5

                  animations:^{ 
                    [buttonCaption setFrame:CGRectMake(buttonCaption.frame.origin.x-diff, 
                                                       buttonCaption.frame.origin.y, 
                                                       buttonCaption.frame.size.width + diff, 
                                                       buttonCaption.frame.size.height)];                


                  } 
                  completion:^(BOOL  completed)
                {
[self nextAnimation:stringsize.width];
                }
  ]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this block animation code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f 
                 animations:^{ 
                     float kOfset = 0.25f;
                     CGFloat newSizeX = buttonCaption.frame.size.width*(1+kOfset);
                     CGFloat ofsetX = buttonCaption.frame.size.width*kOfset;
                     [buttonCaption setFrame:CGRectMake(buttonCaption.frame.origin.x-ofsetX, buttonCaption.frame.origin.y, newSizeX, buttonCaption.frame.size.height)];                
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){  }];
```

Change `kOfset` to value what you want (this is size in %).

Comment: thanks @beryllium, the code expend from right to left, however it does not resize back when the text.width is smaller. care to explain how the code works for me to understand ?

Comment: It's just set a new frame  `[buttonCaption setFrame:...`

Comment: set a new frame to resize back ? i have 5 different string size which i got the value from here CGSize stringsize = [tempCaption sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]]; some might be longer then the others so i need it to resize dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You need the difference between your old width and new width - call this `widthChange`. Then, calculate your new frame as follows:

```
CGRect newFrame = buttonCaption.frame;
newFrame.origin.x -=  widthChange;
newFrame.size.width += widthChange;
```

Now this is the only thing you animate:

```
buttonCaption.frame = newFrame;
```

Basically, you need to move the x origin left at the same time you are extending the width.

Comment: thanks jrturton, will you be able to share some sample code ?

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can add other than what's in my question. Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

```
[buttonCaption setFrame:CGRectMake(110-2,385,stringsize.width +5, stringsize.height)];
```